# passing parameter with eventlistener

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following functions:

```
private function createContent(slideData:Object):void 
  {
   transitions = new Transitions();
   if (slide){
   transitions.applyTransition(slide);
   transitions.addEventListener(Transitions.TRANSITION_COMPLETE, completeHandler);

   }
   slide  = new Slide(slideData);
    addChild(slide);
    transitions.applyTransition(slide);
  }
  private function completeHandler(e:Event):void{
   removeChild(slide);
  }
```

I dispatch an event in the first function and when it comes to the completehandler i would like to delete the slide from the first function but it isnt recognized. How can i pass the slide with the eventlistener so i can remove it in the completeHandler?(i have several instances from slide so i have to pass it through to have the right instance).
Anyone who can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488640

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of ways to pass the slide to the event listener.

- 1/ As a property of the event

  ```
  //Assuming that:
  // 1/ you create a custom Event class that takes two parameters
  //    type: String
  //    slide:Slide
  // 2/ that you have assigned the slide object to a variable in the
  // applyTransition method , which you can then assign to the event
  transitions.dispatchEvent( new TransitionEvent( 
                              Transitions.TRANSITION_COMPLETE , slide ) );
  ```
- 2/ As a property of the dispatcher

  ```
  //Assuming that:
  // you assign the slide object to a variable in the
  // applyTransition method
  private function completeHandler(e:Event):void{
    var target:Transitions = event.currentTarget as Transitions;
    removeChild(target.slide);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the name property of the slide if you wish.

(Though you have not described how & where slide is actually declared - sprite, mc, etc)

**Using name property :**

Set slide as    `slide.name = "instanceName"` (In your first function)

Get slide as `getChildByName("instanceName")` (In your second function)

---

Alternatively you can also:

- Set the slide as    class member,
  accessible by all the    function of
  the class.
- Add reference    of every    slide to
  an array available    as    class
  member to all its functions.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is not dynamic, you could probably use an anonymous function to pass the variable.

```
transitions.addEventListener(Transitions.TRANSITION_COMPLETE, function (evt:Event) {
    completeHandler(evt, variable1, variable2);
});

function completeHandler(evt, catch1, catch2) {
    //do stuff
}
```