# To pass a parameter to event listener in AS3 the simple way... does it exist?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, parameters, addeventlistener

Expected / pseudo example:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick.someWayToPassParameters(true, 123, 4.56, "string"));
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Received " + someWayToRetrieveParameters().b/i/n/s + ".");
}
```

For many years (3~4), on every website, forum, blog, wherever I searched, people tell me there's no simple way to do this. They usually suggest to:

- *Add the listener to a dynamic object, where you can set the value to an extra property and reference it (e.target.property / e.currentTarget.property) in the function.*

  Not all classes are dynamic. It won't work on a Sprite, for example.
- *Extend the class of the object with a custom class to add property or to just make it dynamic.*

  You'll have to create a whole new tweak class everytime.
- *Use an anonymous function as the event handler.*

  There's no reference (and it's ugly). To remove the listener to free resources you're forced to do it from inside the function itself with arguments.callee.
- *Call another function, using the parameter, inside the event handler.*

  And where in the event handler call does the parameter go?
- *Keep the event handler in the same scope as the parameter.*

  Breach to a total semantic mess.
- *Encapsulate both event handler definition and addEventListener call in a function receiving the target and parameters.*

  It can mix scopes, but it's a close one. You have to be careful, though.

...Among many other suggested workarounds.

All I want is just to **pass an argument** to the event handler so I can use it inside its function, just like any normal function!

Am I asking for too much?

Comment: edited my answer to use a separate class which handles handler creation, storage and registration.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Out of the box: it only takes **2 extra lines of elegant code** to solve this ancient puzzle.

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick(true, 123, 4.56, "string"));
function onClick(b:Boolean, i:int, n:Number, s:String):Function {
  return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Received " + b + ", " + i + ", " + n + " and " + s + ".");
  };
}
```

But most importantly, you will very likely need to remove the listener later to free resources, so **+1 line to store it** in a variable:

```
var functionOnClick:Function = onClick(true, 123, 4.56, "string");
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionOnClick);
function onClick(b:Boolean, i:int, n:Number, s:String):Function {
  return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("Received " + b + ", " + i + ", " + n + " and " + s + ".");
  };
}
```

And you'll be able to remove it normally:

```
trace("Before: " + stage.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK));
stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functionOnClick);
trace("After: " + stage.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

---

Here's a more elaborated, dynamic example to prove its use:

```
function onClick(s:String):Function {
  return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("The square " + s + " at x = " + e.currentTarget.x + "px was clicked");
  };
}
var myFunctions:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  myFunctions.push(onClick("#" + (i+1)));
}
for (i = 0; i < myFunctions.length; i++) {
  var square:Sprite = new Sprite();
  square.name = "sqr" + i;
  square.addChild(new Bitmap(new BitmapData(20, 20, false, 0)));
  square.x = 5 + 25 * i;
  square.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunctions[i]);
  stage.addChild(square);
}
```

**No properties through dynamic objects, no custom class, no loose functions, no scope overlap. Just what logic expects it to be: you're simply passing arguments to it.**

And to remove every listener properly, you can do it like this later:

```
for (i = 0; i < myFunctions.length; i++) {
  square = stage.getChildByName("sqr" + i) as Sprite;
  trace("Before (#" + (i+1) + "): " + square.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK));
  square.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myFunctions[i]);
  trace("After (#" + (i+1) + "): " + square.hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK));
  stage.removeChild(square);
}
```

IMHO this is the simplest yet most solid way to do it.

Comment: Of course it is. It's actually "safety-oriented": the lifespan of the function lasts until you get its returning listener, whose reference can be kept in a variable for a sure removal posteriorly. You have control over everything.

Answer (score 8):

### here is an example

```
var s1:Boolean = true;

station1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(e:MouseEvent) : void { spread(e, s1) });
station1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, function(e:MouseEvent) : void { collapse(e, s1) });


function spread(event:MouseEvent ,bb:Boolean):void {
 if(bb != true) event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay(2);
}

function collapse(event:MouseEvent,bb:Boolean ):void {
    if(bb != true) event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay(18);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use AS3-Signals? Passing a parameter then is as simple as:

```
import org.osflash.signals.Signal;

public class AlarmClock 
{
    public var alarm:Signal;

    public function AlarmClock() 
    {
        alarm = new Signal(String);
    }

    public function ring():void
    {
        alarm.dispatch("9 AM");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a parameter directly to the event handler is not possible.

The best approximation is by using a function factory method, IMO

//--EDITED:
I created a separate class to maintain parameterized handlers, see https://gist.github.com/4124722

usage is simple:

```
    public class Usage extends Sprite{

        private var _handlers : ParameterizedHandlerContainer;

        public function ParameterizedEvents()
        {

            _handlers = new ParameterizedHandlerContainer();
            _handlers.registerHandler( this, Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, someMethod, 3000 );
        }

        private function someMethod( event : Event, amount : uint ):void
        {
            trace( this, 'someMethod', amount );
            _handlers.destroyHandler( arguments.callee, event );
        }


    }
```

Now you can register parameterized handlers with `ParameterizedHandlerContainer#registerHandler` and destroy them with `ParameterizedHandlerContainer#destroyHandler`.

You can pass in any amount of parameters you want, but the first parameter of the callback method must be of type Event or a descendant.

Comment: Edited my answer, abstracted it and added the possibility of removing the handler

Answer (score -1):

I would modify Creynders example slightly:

```
    protected function createHandler(handler:Function, ...args):Function
    {
        var h:Function = function(e:Event = null):void
        {
            trace(args);

            if (handler != null)
                handler(e);
        }
        return h;
    }

    sm.addEventListener(StyleEvent.STYLE_CHANGE, 
            createHandler(updateStyle, 1,true,"Lorem",["a","b","c"]), 
            false, 0, true);
```

this way you can use original event handlers and inject the "arguments" to it,

also you could have your handlers to have following signature:

```
protected function myHandler(e:Event, ...args):void;
```

then you could pass arguments directly to the target handler:

```
    protected function createHandler(handler:Function, ...args):Function
    {
        var h:Function = function(e:Event = null):void
        {
            //trace(args);

            if (handler != null)
            {
                args.unshift(e);
                handler.apply(this, args);
            }
        }
        return h;
    }
```

best regards