# generating random color for a square

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a button in flash and I want to generate an automatic color for my square.

I have this function

```
private function btnClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

        var mycolor :ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
        mycolor.color = (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
        parcare.transform.colorTranform = mycolor;
        }
```

I get this error

```
: 4 Error: Access of undefined property parcare. parcare.transform.colorTranform = mycolor;
```

Do you know how can I solve it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a scope problem, the random colour generating is fine

the `onClick` function is outside of the scope of the rest of your class. You need to find a way for the function to know what the variable `parcare` is.

There is no easy way of fixing it for you without seeing more code.

look a at this question for more info [To pass a parameter to event listener in AS3 the simple way... does it exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486230/to-pass-a-parameter-to-event-listener-in-as3-the-simple-way-does-it-exist)

Answer (score 0):

To create a random hex color is:

```
'#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

And As A function is:

```
function random() {
    var a = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    return a;
}
```